# How do I change the Magento default invoice

Tags: magento-1.9

I have been told it is not possible to display my company name, registration and VAT number at the bottom of the Magento default invoice. I'm sure this is rubbish but I'm not sure where to make the changes.
Could someone possibly show me the code for the default magento invoice with the following included 
"Company name and reg line 1" and 
Company VAT line 2"

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Templates can be changed any way you like.

1. Look into app/locale/{lang_country}/template/email/sales/invoice_new.html

**Again I don't know if your path would be the same. Conceptually, you are looking at the template to determine what is called for the footer(if anything). Here is where you will make your changes or create a totally new file to edit your footer.

2. Change the config path for invoices to your new template (if you chose to create a new file). In admin this should be:

   ```
   Configuration->Sales->Sales Emails->Invoice Email Template
   ```

Comment: I think he is talking about the invoice .pdf itself and not the email sent for a new invoice

Comment: I think I should have made my challenge a little clearer :-( Legally I have to show my company details and VAT details on both the emailed invoice and PDF printed invoice.

Answer (score 0):

The file that renders the invoice pdf is

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

Copy this file to

> app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

In this new file add the following function or anything like that.

```
protected function _drawFooter(Zend_Pdf_Page $page, $store = null){
    $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
    $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0, 0, 0));
    $this->y -= 10;
    $page->drawLine(25, $this->y-200, 570, $this->y-200);

    $store_name = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/name', $store);
    $store_vatn = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/merchant_vat_number', $store);

    $page->drawText($store_name. '  '. $store_vatn , 35, $this->y-230, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Then in the getPdf() function, add

```
    $this->_drawFooter($page);
```

just before $this->_afterGetPdf();

It should look something like

```
    public function getPdf($invoices = array())
    {...
            /* Add totals */
            $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                Mage::app()->getLocale()->revert();
            }
        }
        $this->_drawFooter($page);
        $this->_afterGetPdf();
        return $pdf;
    }
```

Comment: I really don't know what you mean by "company registration"

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/315565/57334 any help thanks @Yiorgos Moschovitis